# ¿Como pasar de los binarios del ascii 8-bit a los binarios del ascii 6-bit?

Tags: vb.net, ascii

¿Como pasar de los binarios del ascii 8-bit a los binarios del ascii 6-bit?

**Por ejemplo, ¿existe o no un vinculo entre H en 8-bit ASCII `0100 1000` y H en 6-bit ASCII `011000`?**

Me refiero al [articulo de Eric S. Raymond](http://catb.org/gpsd/AIVDM.html#_aivdm_aivdo_payload_armoring) que fue editado dos veces recientemente sobre las tablas de conversion entre el ASCII y el binario.Aqui esta como recobrar los 6-bits.pero no el binario:

> To recover the six bits, subtract 48 from the ASCII character value; if the result is greater than 40 subtract 8.

si eso es muy claro para los decimales

```
Char ASCII Decimal Bits

"0"  48    0       000000 
"1"  49    1       000001
"2"  50    2       000010
"3"  51    3       000011
 ...
```

No lo esta para las letras

```
"H"  72    24      011000
```

He hecho el siguiente codigo para recupererar los binaries asociados con los simbolos ascii. **Pero si me da `000001` por 1 en ASCII, que esta acertado, me da `1000101` por la letra `u` en lugar de `111101`**

```js
Module Module1

    Public Function traduction_ASCII(trames As String)

        Dim binario_en_8 As Integer = 0
        Dim dec As Integer = 0
        Dim Remainder As Integer
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim tabular_binario(40) As String


        'Modificamos los elementos ASCII en binarios'
        For i = 0 To trames.Length - 1
            'Recuperamos el valor numerica del ASCII leido en 8 bits'
            binario_en_8 = Asc(trames.ElementAt(i))

            'est esta necesario pero no se porque'
            dec = Val(binaire_en_8)

            'la modificamos en su valor ASCII en 6 bits'
            dec = dec - 48
            If dec > 40 Then
                dec = dec - 8
            End If

            While dec > 0
                remainder = dec Mod 2
                dec /= 2
                result = Remainder.ToString & result
                j = j + 1
            End While

            While j < 6    
                result = "0" & result
                j = j + 1
            End While

            tableau_binario(i) = result
            result = ""
            j = 0
        Next

        Return traduction_binaire_de_ASCII
    End Function
End Module
```

El error es que para el programa, `1F / 2 = 8` en lugar de `7`
pero no sé porque divide por esta manera

Comment: El cómo pasar de ASCII a esa codificación 6bit ASCII lo has puesto tu mismo. No veo la duda.

Comment: @DanielFaro, en efecto, no es complicado pero no estoy capaz realisarlo en VB.NET

Comment: Tienes que decir de que lenguaje estamos hablando en la etiqueta.

Comment: 6 bits u 8 bits si el caracter es ASCII, no se pierde su valor, la 'H' como mencionas, es `011000 == 00011000 == 11000` == `24` en decimal. ¿Qué es realmente lo que quieres lograr? ¿Cuál es la salida que esperas y qué obtienes con lo intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: @NaCl lo he puesto en negrito que si me da `000001` por `1` en ASCII, que esta acertado, me da `1000101` por la letra u en lugar de `111101`, la razon es que por el programa, 1F / 2 = 8 en lugar de 7 pero no sé porque divide por esta manera

Comment: @Marine1: / es una división en coma flotante, en la que 15 / 2 = 7.5. Para realizar una división entera, usa \, en la que 15 \ 2 = 7

Answer (score -1):

Se puede hacer manipulación de bits o usar la clase [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx). Usando esta última, se deben reacomodar los bits en formato [MSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit).

También se puede aprovechar la implementación nativa para [Base 64](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) que viene con la clase [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) de .Net. Para este caso lo único que se debe tener en cuenta es reemplazar las tablas de codificación y verificar los símbolos de relleno.

```js
' Tabla Base 64 '
Const TABLA_BASE64 As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

' Tabla AIVD tomada de "Table 2. ASCII payload armoring" del artículo "AIVDM/AIVDO protocol decoding" de Eric S. Raymond '
Const TABLA_AIVD As String = "0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw"
```

Codificación:

```js
Dim Texto as String = "Texto a codificar"

' Codifica en base 64 '
Dim cod as String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Texto))

' Elimina los símbolos de relleno finales '
If cod.EndsWith("==") Then
    cod = cod.Substring(0, cod.Length - 2)
ElseIf cod.EndsWith("=") Then
    cod = cod.Substring(0, cod.Length - 1)
End If

' Reemplaza los símbolos de Base 64 por los de AIVD'
dim sb as system.text.stringbuilder = new system.text.stringbuilder
dim pos as integer
For Each ch As Char In cod
    pos = TABLA_BASE64.IndexOf(ch)
    sb.Append(TABLA_AIVD(pos))
Next

' Texto codificado en AIVD '
cod = sb.tostring
```

Decodificación:

```js
' Reemplaza los símbolos de AIVD por los de Base 64 '
dim sb as system.text.stringbuilder = new system.text.stringbuilder
dim pos as integer
For Each ch As Char In cod
    pos = TABLA_AIVD.IndexOf(ch)
    sb.Append(TABLA_BASE64(pos))
Next

' Agrega los símbolos de relleno para Base 64 '
Dim m as integer = sb.Length Mod 4

If m Then
    sb.Append("="c, 4 - m)
End If

' Texto decodificado '
dim Texto as string = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(sb.ToString))
```

Este método se puede usar en cualquier sistema de codificación de 8 bits en 6, con la tabla de símbolos correspondiente.